# Django custom middleware request.user always AnonymousUser

Tags: django, django-middleware

I'm using **Django 2.2** and **DRF**

In my application, based on the user property, I need to change the `request.user` to a different user.

```
class CustomMiddleware:
  def __init__(self, get_response):
     self.get_response = get_response

  def __call__(self, request):
     print(request.user)

     response = self.get_response(request)
     return response
```

The `print(request.user)` always gives `AnonymousUser` object but it gives the authenticated user in the views.

**How can I get the user in the middleware?**

Middleware hierarchy

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django_hosts.middleware.HostsRequestMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'silk.middleware.SilkyMiddleware',
    'django_hosts.middleware.HostsResponseMiddleware',

    'oauth2_provider.middleware.OAuth2TokenMiddleware',
    'myapp.middleware.CustomMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: Can you post your list on middlewares from settings?

Comment: You should put the middelware in the correct order, so after the authentication middleware.

Comment: The middleware is at the last of all middlewares

Comment: @AnujTBE: and the `AuthenticationMiddleware` is part of the middlewares?

Comment: Add list of all middlewares, the `CustomMiddleware` is at the last

Comment: same problem. anyone answer this please? tqvm

Comment: @TianLoon I have answered the question with the solution which worked for me. Hope it will work for you as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using `oauth2_provider.backends.OAuth2Backend` to the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` list.

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'oauth2_provider.backends.OAuth2Backend',
    # Uncomment following if you want to access the admin
    #'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
    '...',
)
```