# Django Custom Middleware gets AnonymousUser even for logged in users

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-middleware

I'm using a custom middleware that looks like this:

```
class DisallowLoggedInUsers:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.
        print("in interceptor before response")
        print("user: ", request.user)
        print("is_authenticated?: ", request.user.is_authenticated)

        response = self.get_response(request)

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.
        print("in interceptor after response")
        print("user: ", request.user)
        print("is_authenticated?: ", request.user.is_authenticated)

        return response
```

I also have similar logs inside the `get` method of the view.
Here's the log output:

```
in interceptor before response
user: AnonymousUser
is_authenticated? False

in view
user: John Doe/john@test.domain
is_authenticated?  True

in interceptor after response
user: John Doe/john@test.domain
is_authenticated?  True
```

Here is my order of middlewares:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'userdata.customInterceptor.DisallowLoggedInUsers',
]
```

Even though I've put my custom middleware way down the order (below `AuthenticationMiddleware`, the `request.user` object is not set untill the view is processed. I even tried trapping the request at `process_view` of the middleware but got an AnonymousUser there still.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm on Django `3.1.7` and djangorestframework `3.12.3`.

Note: I checked [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60846831/django-custom-middleware-request-user-always-anonymoususer), but it did not help.

Comment: How does your authentication working?

Comment: why not use the loggedintequiredmixin https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin

Comment: Since you are using DRF, the authentication is at the view level. That's why the user is only visible after `get_response`

Comment: @Dimitris Kougioumtzis thanks, but I want to only allow "non" logged in users.